UITextView Line wrapping not detecting
I have this Uiviewrepresentable with line numbers that works good enough, however when a line wraps around the line numbers don't detect that. I used "enumerateLineFragments" but that uses the wrapped lines as separate ones. I am very new to UIKit and this is the best I could come up with because open source libraries don't work particularly well and are very complex. Thanks in advance.
Here is my code. I can be used like this: "CodeEditor(text: $text)"
import SwiftUI

struct CodeEditor: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String
    
    var textView = LineNumberedTextView()
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> LineNumberedTextView {
        textView.isEditable = true
        textView.delegate = context.coordinator
        textView.font = UIFont.monospacedSystemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .regular)
        textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        textView.textContainer.lineBreakMode = .byCharWrapping
        return textView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: LineNumberedTextView, context: Context) {
        if text != uiView.text {
            uiView.text = text
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
        var parent: CodeEditor
        
        init(_ parent: CodeEditor) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            self.parent.text = textView.text
        }
        func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
            self.parent.textView.currentLines = textView.text.lineNumbersForRange(textView.selectedRange) ?? []
            self.parent.textView.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
}

extension String {
    func lineNumbersForRange(_ range: NSRange) -> [Int]? {
        guard
            let startIndex = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: range.location, limitedBy: self.endIndex),
            let endIndex = self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.length, limitedBy: self.endIndex)
        else {
            return nil
        }
        
        let substring = self[startIndex..<endIndex]
        var lineNumbers: [Int] = []
        
        // Find the lines within the range
        let linesInRange = substring.components(separatedBy: .newlines)
        
        // Calculate the number of newline characters before the start index
        let lineBreaksBeforeStartIndex = self[..<startIndex].components(separatedBy: .newlines).count - 1
        
        // Iterate over each line within the range
        for (index, _) in linesInRange.enumerated() {
            // Calculate the line number for each line within the range
            let lineNumber = lineBreaksBeforeStartIndex + index + 1
            lineNumbers.append(lineNumber)
        }
        
        return lineNumbers
    }
}


class LineNumberedTextView: UITextView {
    let lineNumberGutterWidth: CGFloat = 40
    let lineNumberPadding: CGFloat = 5
    
    var currentLines: [Int] = []
    
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.alignment = .right
        
        let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            .font: UIFont.monospacedSystemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .ultraLight),
            .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
            .foregroundColor: UIColor(white: 0.8, alpha: 1)
        ]
        let attributes_active: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            .font: UIFont.monospacedSystemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .ultraLight),
            .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
            .foregroundColor: UIColor.black
        ]
        
        var lineNum = 1
        
        var lineRect = CGRect.zero
        
        layoutManager.enumerateLineFragments(forGlyphRange: NSRange(location: 0, length: textStorage.length)) { (rect, usedRect, textContainer, glyphRange, stop) in
            
            print("Line \(lineNum): H: \(rect.height)")
            
            lineRect = CGRect(x: 5, y: rect.origin.y + self.textContainerInset.top, width: self.lineNumberGutterWidth - self.lineNumberPadding, height: rect.height)
            let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "\(lineNum)", attributes: self.currentLines.contains(lineNum) ? attributes_active : attributes)
            attributedString.draw(in: lineRect)
            lineNum += 1
        }
        
        if self.textStorage.string.isEmpty {
            let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "\(lineNum)", attributes: self.currentLines.contains(lineNum) ? attributes_active : attributes)
            attributedString.draw(at: CGPoint(x: self.lineNumberGutterWidth - self.lineNumberPadding - 5, y: self.textContainerInset.top))
        }
        
        if self.textStorage.string.hasSuffix("\n") {
            let rect = lineRect.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: lineRect.height)
            let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "\(lineNum)", attributes: self.currentLines.contains(lineNum) ? attributes_active : attributes)
            attributedString.draw(in: rect)
            print(rect)
        }
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: textContainerInset.top, left: lineNumberGutterWidth, bottom: textContainerInset.bottom, right: textContainerInset.right)
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    
    override var text: String! {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
}



Can't use self like this Coordinator(self) because self here is a value not an object reference.
In update, you need to use the changed binding value to set something like a new closure on the coordinator that uses the new binding.
make needs to init the UIView, so it happens once, you shouldn't init objects as struct vars in SwiftUI, it's a memory leak.
